# How to included joined data in a loop

Tags: laravel, join

I am displaying a list on my blade view which contains data from the display table: name, school and IP.

The school is saved as a school id in this table.

The Schools table contains the list of ids and related schools.

I want to use the school names from the schools table and display them on my blade view.

I can get this data separately.

This gets all the data from the display table

```
$records = DB::table('display')->paginate(10);
```

This gets all the school name from the schools table.

```
$schools = DB::table('schools')
   ->join('display', 'schools.id', '=', 'display.school')  
   ->select('schools.name')
   ->get();
```

To display the data from the display table I'm using a foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($records as $record)
{{ $record->name }}
{{ $record->school }}
{{ $record->ip }}
@endforeach
```

I don't know how to insert the school name into the space where currently $record->school appears. $record->school displays the school ID, but I want to display the school name which is saved in the school table.

Display model

```
public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
```

School model

```
public function display()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Display');
    }
```

Comment: do you have models, eloquent relations?

Comment: I do have them set up

Comment: what are the fields in schools table? i believe the display table contains: name, school and ip

Comment: The schools table contains id and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have models and Eloquent relations, you can simply use it:

**Controller**

```php
$records = Display::with('school')->paginate(10);
```

**Blade view**

```html
@foreach ($records as $record)
  {{ $record->name }}
  {{ $record->school->name }} <!-- school name via relation -->
  {{ $record->ip }}
@endforeach
```

**Display Model**

```php
class Display extends Model
{
    public function school()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\School');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I hadn't set up the relationship in the database itself and had to do a new migration.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using Eloquent as it makes life so much easier. However, using DB, you need code similar to below, where you are joining schools as a relationship to display.

```
 $records = DB::table('display')
  ->join('schools', 'schools.id', '=', 'display.school')  
  ->paginate(10);

@foreach ($records as $record)
  {{ $record->name }}
  {{ $record->schools->name }}
  {{ $record->ip }}
@endforeach
```